# ul no margin on first level of nested list?

Tags: css, list, margin, html-lists

I want a styled list that doesn't have a margin-left on the first level.. But does on subsequent, leveled sublists.. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<ul>
<li>no margin</li>
<li>
    <ul>
    <li>yes margin</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

(without adding css classes to the first level of ul or changing any of the code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the first ul a direct descendant of the body? I know you said not adding css classes to the code but I presume adding stuff to a stylesheet is not out the question?
If so you could use a style declaration like:

```
body > ul{
 margin-left:0px;
}
```

or if you know a div it does sit within:

```
#your_id > ul{
margin-left:0px;
}
```

There may also be default padding you need to consider.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the > css selector!

Comment: @Wesley: note that [`>` doesn’t work in IE 6](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3E_%28child_selector%29).

Answer (score 11):

If you want this to apply to all `<ul>`s on every page the stylesheet is applied to, this works:

```
ul {/* Remove margin for all <ul>s (and padding, because different browsers have different default styles) */
     margin-left: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
}

ul ul {/* Add a margin for any <ul> inside another <ul> */
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

But if you only want it to apply to certain lists, you need to add something to the HTML to identify those lists (as the other answers have suggested).

Answer (score 4):

You should probably clear the margin of the main `<ul>`, and then set the margin for a `<ul>` that's in an `<li>` element.

```
ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

li > ul {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, but a small complementation to TommyBs's answer: you need to apply the id you use in the html list item tag, like so:

```
<ul>
<li id="your_id">no margin</li>
<li>
    <ul>
    <li>yes margin</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And in the css the corresponding line would be

```
li#your_id {
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was default margins, and I set them 0
`-webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;`